# Which grease is for what?

Tags: grease

I used to think as simple as lubcirants and grease, now that I'm off to buy grease to assemble a bike I'm confronted with dozens of different types of greases.

Does it matter what grease I buy? If absolutely not what grease do I use for what?

Comment: Can you describe what components / materials you'll be assembling? Carbon, Al alloy, steel? You can do most jobs with just one, or maybe two, if we know the combination of materials.

Comment: Carbon for sure, Carbon seattube, Al forktube.. bottom bracket and pedals need some too. I've read moving parts (high temperature) need different grease than non moving parts (low temperature)

Comment: Grease mostly universal for metal component and any moving parts other than the chain. For any bolt-in stuff, heavy duty grease/anti-seize should do the job. For bottom bracket, bearing, some use suggest using water-resistant grease. Just skip graphite.

Comment: And anything carbon on carbon you need a carbon fibre specific compount, neither a grease nor an oil.   And a torque wrench for clamps onto carbon... don't use the mechanic's elbow to measure torque!

Comment: I don't know if links are allowed here but this product here, in the description they say I can use it on just about anything?? http://www.bike-discount.de/en/buy/dynamic-assembly-paste-80g-26883 Bad Idea?

Comment: @Azul Shiva: That paste would be good for anything where carbon meets carbon or whatever else in a static contact. But it's not meant to be used as GREASE between moving parts.

Comment: Unless you have an exotic bike, any decent quality standard bike grease should work for moving parts.  However, while automotive grease will work in a pinch, use bike grease if you can, as it's designed to perform better in the dirt/moisture environment of a bike.  (I've used Phil Wood products in the past, but don't know if they are still available.  Park products should be equally trustworthy.)  But if you want something for anti-seize purposes (vs a "lube") use a product specific to the materials you're working with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only question I would have is if the bike is Carbon Fiber or not. I'm guessing it's not and is an alloy (metal) bike. Just like cars, there are tons of stuff people will try to sell with magical properties. Ignore them.

There are two greases I use: The first is because it is everywhere, cheap and easy to apply thanks to the tube:

[image: Park PolyLube]

If you want more grease for your money, you can't beat Lucas Marine Grease:

[image: Lucas Marine Grease]

In the end either will do the job very well. The marine grease is longer lasting and theoretically more rust resistant. But I use it because it does the job well, a tube lasts forever (use a plastic spoon to dig some out when needed) and it's thicker than Park's stuff.

I carry the Park stuff with me on a mobile job because it is easy to apply and customers like names they recognize.  The cost is the same for either. I'd vote for Park due to convenience.

Answer (score 0):

I got poly lube made for bikes. Your link says protection from twisting. This makes me worry. It may add resistance to twisting like all bearings do.