# is this grease usable for bikes?

Tags: grease

i want to buy some grease for my bike and i found this kind of [grease](https://www.lazada.com.my/catalog/?spm=a2o4k.home.search.1.42fe24f6LGZhX6&q=wheel%20bearing%20grease&_keyori=ss&from=search_history&sugg=wheel%20bearing%20grease_0_1). i think those grease are for cars so it might be different from the grease for bicycles but im not sure. if that grease is not suitable, what kind of grease should i look for?

Comment: The link shows lots of different greases, which one do you mean?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/41477/ and also relevant are https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/30992/ and https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/42993/   Go read all those answers and apply them to your situation.

Comment: More reading here: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4607/what-makes-grease-appropriate-for-bikes

Answer (score -1):

Given the selections within your link, I would choose this [marine grease](https://www.lazada.com.my/products/mercury-precision-lubricants-marine-grease-2-4-c-with-ptfe-nlgi-2-i455990707-s702198198.html?spm=a2o4k.searchlist.list.14.490d641ffXDgrV&search=1) with PTFE.  This product is waterproof as it is marketed as marine grease, and can hold up in all weather conditions that I find myself biking in.  Also, this grease contains the ingredient, PTFE, which has proven to have superior anti-friction properties.  Also known by the brand name, Teflon, one finds this ingredient common to the most popular and recommended bike lubes.  Tri-Flow, for example.

Comment: You need more than just "is waterproof" and "contains PTFE". Is the viscosity of this grease appropriate to use in bicycles?

Comment: I'm quite comfortable with my answer especially within the scope of OP's question which provided a link to a catalog page of several types grease for various applications. While a discussion point regarding viscosity and it's role in lubrication has obvious relevance generally, for bicycle applications viscosity's importance is mainly reduced to ease of use. The forces involved in bicycling (heat, pressure, speed) are far under tolerances that need concern us their effect on most all grease.  Water is a different matter, and marine grease is often cited by bike-people as an excellent choice

Comment: @David Richerby I guess I feel that when asked to pick the best option from a given set, what is needed is my selection and a brief reasoning. My choice was solid, complete, and not at all unique in bike world tips   Essentially I resent the down vote--but you'll have that from time to time in operations this size

Comment: Your answer gives no real indication that the grease you've chosen is actually suitable. The correct answer to "Which of these is best?" could well be "None of them" so just picking one isn't guaranteed to be right.